# How to enqueue an external Javascript file to Frontpage footer

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, footer

I am trying to add an external Javascript file from my plugin. My code is -

```
<?php 
/******
 * 
 * Plugin Name: Image Zoom
 * Author: Kallol Das   
 * Description: This plugin will zoom an image of WordPress posts.
 * version: 1.0
 * 
 *******/

 function zoom_image_main_js_init(){

 wp_enqueue_script('zoom-script', plugins_url('/js/zoom-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 1.0, true);

 }

add_action('init', 'zoom_image_main_js_init');
```

Now the problem is It's only enqueuing in admin footer But not in Frontpage footer. So, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `init` use `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which is used to enqueue styles and scripts in front-end.

Also, for backend enqueue use `admin_enqueue_scripts`.

Comment: Now it gets worst. Script is not enqueued in Frontpage nor in Admin page.

Comment: Do you have `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in your header and footer?

Comment: Just let me check.

Comment: @AniruddhaGawade It's not a good practice to use `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()` to enqueue the scripts. May be he is facing the cache issues.

Comment: I think `wp_head` and `wp_footer` and must use in your theme, without which all the plugin will break.

Comment: When I follow your suggestion, my problem solved. Yes, @the_dramatist it was a cash issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check this below code-

```
function zoom_image_main_js_init() {
    if( is_front_page() || is_home() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('zoom-script', plugins_url('/js/zoom-script.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'zoom_image_main_js_init' );
```

Here I'm hooking `zoom_image_main_js_init` function to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and inside `zoom_image_main_js_init` function I'm checking if it is front page or not by calling `is_front_page()` function inside `if` condition.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Still its not working

Comment: Clear you cache and reload it again. And please tell again clearly what problem you're facing. @KallolDas

Comment: And also check the updated answer. Hope it helps.